# Максимальное количество (или размер) аргументов, которые можно передать скрипту?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, kernel

Имеется ли какое-либо ограничение на количество передаваемых аргументов скрипту?

Предположим, скрипт может принимать максимально 116 аргументов. А если максимальное число аргументов, которые может принять скрипт (предположим 13000) - никаких проблем не возникнет?

Comment: максимум может быть 2^32-1 вроде , но также есть и максимум длины одного аргумента, скажем строки

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, а где вы это чисто взяли, не подскажете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевод [отсюда](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/):

### Количество аргументов и максимальная длина одного аргумента

Как минимум, в Linux 2.6 есть также ограничение на максимальное количество аргументов в `argv[]`. В Linux 2.6.14 функция `do_execve()` в `fs/exec.c` проверяет, превышает ли количество:

```
PAGE_SIZE*MAX_ARG_PAGES-sizeof(void *) / sizeof(void *)
```

В 32-бит Linux, это **ARGMAX/4-1** (32767). Это ограничение начинает влиять, если средняя длина аргументов меньше 4.

Начиная с Linux 2.6.23, эта функция проверяет превышает ли количество **MAX_ARG_STRINGS** в `<linux/binfmts.h>` (2^32-1 = 4294967296-1).

И как дополнительное ограничение начиная с 2.6.23, длина одного аргумента не должна превышать **MAX_ARG_STRLEN** (131072).

Ещё достаточно подробный ответ, со ссылками на коммиты и дополнительной информацией - [здесь](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842)

Comment: А что можете сказать по поводу **xargs --show-limits**?

Comment: В принципе, да, в вашем ответе имеются некоторые цифры из этого!

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk, xargs дополнительно считает размер переменных окружения, который соответственно уменьшает максимально доступный размер буфера для аргументов